# Golang map/array (non-struct) serialization

Tags: serialization, go, deserialization

I do lot of queries resulting in map or slice/array of map, something like this:

```
// package M
type SX map[string]interface{}
type IX map[int64]interface{}
type IAX map[int64][]interface{}
type SAX map[string][]interface{}
type SS map[string]string
type SF map[string]float64
type II map[int64]int64
type IB map[int64]bool
type SI map[string]int64
type IS map[int64]string
type SB map[string]bool

// package A
type X []interface{}
type MSX []map[string]interface{}
```

So I could declare it something like this:

```
 // import `gitlab.com/kokizzu/gokil/A`
 // import `gitlab.com/kokizzu/gokil/M`
values := M.SX{
    `orderId`:  `1-12-1`,
    `apiKey`:   `16313c061a8e3288528123bd8`,
    `country`:  `360`, 
    `currency`: `360`, 
    `payType`:  1,
    `items`: A.MSX{
        M.SX{
            `code`:  `subscription for 7 days`,
            `name`:  `Bla bla`,
            `price`: price,
        },
    },
    `profile`: M.SX{
        `entry`: A.MSX{
            M.SX{
                `key`:   `need_mno_id`,
                `value`: `yes`,
            },
            M.SX{
                `key`:   `foo`,
                `value`: `bar`,
            },
        },
    },
    `profile`: A.MSX{
        M.SX{`foo`:`bar`,`age`:123},
        M.SX{`foo`:`wow`,`age`:234,`currency`:360},
        M.SX{`foo`:`such`,`age`:45,`is_admin`:true},
        M.SX{`foo`:`wow`,`age`:57,`is_deleted`:true},
    },
}
```

Which one of the [list](https://github.com/alecthomas/go_serialization_benchmarks) other than `encoding/gob` and `encoding/json`, that support this kind of serialization (no need to generate struct/schema)?

```
github.com/alecthomas/binary
github.com/davecgh/go-xdr/xdr
github.com/Sereal/Sereal/Go/sereal
github.com/ugorji/go/codec
gopkg.in/vmihailenco/msgpack.v2 --> has example for enc/dec-ing a map
labix.org/v2/mgo/bson
github.com/tinylib/msgp (code generator for msgpack)
github.com/golang/protobuf (generated code)
github.com/gogo/protobuf (generated code, optimized version of goprotobuf)
github.com/DeDiS/protobuf (reflection based)
github.com/google/flatbuffers
github.com/hprose/hprose-go/io
github.com/glycerine/go-capnproto
zombiezen.com/go/capnproto2
github.com/andyleap/gencode
github.com/pascaldekloe/colfer
```

**Note**: there is nothing wrong with `Gob` (currently I use them), I just need to prepare for the alternative (or start with the best one) when `Gob` no longer suffice (not fast/small enough) since I use it to cache the database (with ever changing schema) queries result on RAM.

Comment: github.com/golang/protobuf works really well.

Answer (score 1):

Your data structures look like they can be represented as several tables of
data. That is, normalised into tables (like with database tables). If that is
the case, then consider using a table-based subset of FlatBuffers.

I have just released a Go library and utility that does that. All you need to
do is redesign your data structures into tabular format and represent them
in a simple table data format, then install and run a utility gotflat which
will generate all the glue for you. The following link shows how to install
and use it. I hope that helps.

https://github.com/urban-wombat/gotablesutils/releases/tag/v0.2-alpha